# how to show multiple node content in graph (Cytoscape stylesheet)

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js

I want to display two node content(node id and node name) associated with node.The following code overrides the first style.How can we display multiple content in graph.

```
 style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
 .selector('node')
  .css({
    'content': 'data(name)',
    'text-valign': 'center',
     'text-halign': 'center',
     })
  .selector('node')
   .css({
    'content': 'data(id)',
    'text-valign': 'top',
     'text-halign': 'center',
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a different selector on the second node if you don't want to override it.

Comment: But I need to show two contents on the same node.One is on the center of the node and one is on the top of the node.

Comment: Then you will need to specify the data source in the HTML, instead of the CSS